# WPF list of images in GridViewCell

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview

Is there a tutorial or something that explains, how to display lists of data (eg a list of images) in a single cell of a GridView Cell/DataTemplate?

---

The source data for the ListView/GridView is something like this:

```
class Item
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public int Age { get; set; }

  public string Mail { get; set; }

  public List<ItemImages> Images { get; set; }
}

class ItemImages
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, one of the members that shall be displayed inside a cell is a list itself. Doesn't matter if it's a list of images, strings or whatever.

Im' just looking for a starting point on how to display any kind of lists in a cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is really simple. You should populate items control such as `ComboBox`. Let me show an example:

XAML:

```
<ListView Margin="10" Name="listView">
   <ListView.View>
       <GridView>
           <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
           <GridViewColumn Header="Age" Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Age}" />
           <GridViewColumn Header="Mail" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Mail}" />
           <GridViewColumn Header="Images">
              <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                   <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Images}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
                </DataTemplate>
              </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
          </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class FooBarSample : Window
{
   public FooBarSample()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       PopulateCollection()
   }
}

private void PopulateCollection()
{
   ObservableCollection<Item> items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
   items.Add(new Item() { Name = "Jack London", Age = 42, Mail = "jackLondon@london-family.com", Images = new List<ItemImages>()
   {
      new ItemImages() {Name="1" }, new ItemImages() {Name="2" }, new ItemImages() {Name="3" },
   } });
   listView.ItemsSource = items;
```

}